# How to use Firefox browser in android automation

Tags: android, firefox, appium

I am using Appium version: 1.4.13. Please look at my desire capabilities:

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "selendroid");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, Platform.ANDROID);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "5.1.1");
capabilities.setCapability("androidPackage", "org.mozilla.firefox");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "org.mozilla.firefox.App");
```

when I run my test, firefox fires at my android device but at the same time I get an error.

```
Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html
```

Would anyone tell me, What I have missed?

Comment: try running removing browser name capability

Comment: I tried, but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I know Appium cannot use Firefox, since it is not implemented yet.

More information:
https://discuss.appium.io/t/firefox-on-android/2492/5